# how to optimize joining (on text) with FTS3

Tags: sqlite

1. Dose the FTS3 functionality works fast with the JOIN gueries?
2. if it dose, guide me to convert my tables. I have 2 tables with millions of records (edges and nodes). I have to join them on 2 column in which the columns contents are text.
   the basic working query is (but slow):

   ```
   select * from EDGES
   inner join NODES on EDGES.sourcename = NODES.name
   or EDGES.targetname = NODES.name
   ```
3. if not, is there any faster way to get the result? the database is 15GB and this query may take more than 2 days.

the tables are like

NODES of interest between allNODES are:

```
name        address
---------------------
yahoo       yahoo.com
google      google.com
MSN         MSN.com
```

All edges

```
sourcename     targetname 
--------------------------
MSN            google
yahoo          google
google         MSN
amazon         google
amazon         yahoo
yahoo          amazon
amazon         stackoverflow
stackoverflow  amazon
MSN            amazon
```

the result may look like this:

```
sourcename     targetname 
--------------------------
MSN            google
yahoo          google
google         MSN
amazon         google
amazon         yahoo
yahoo          amazon
MSN            amazon
```

Comment: Using full text search for finding edges or nodes in a graph seems like a really... unusual... choice of database design. You should show your table definitions and indexes, and sample data and what you want the results using that sample to look like. Explaining exactly what you're trying to accomplish would help too, since this smells like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Updated:  the nodes are webpage names. I have a list of 21000 selected pages to graph the connections. that is to  search in the the edges table for those selected webpage which are linked whether it is a source or a target .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear on what you're trying to get result-wise, but you can dramatically shrink the size of the database and speed up queries by doing some basic cleanup like using integers instead of strings for the `edges` [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). (Integers take up less space and are a *lot* faster to compare than strings, so you want to use them as much as possible for relations)

First, make an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column of your node table to alias the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                 , name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE 
                 , address TEXT);
INSERT INTO nodes(name, address) VALUES
  ('google', 'google.com')
, ('MSN', 'microsoft.com');
-- etc.
```

(I assume that names are unique; if not you'll want to make the appropriate change and add a normal index on the column (edit: I suspect you don't have an index on `nodes.name`, which would help explain a really slow query)).

Then make your edges table reference the id column instead of the name one (Also assuming that each `(source,dest)` pair is unique):

```
CREATE TABLE edges(source INTEGER REFERENCES nodes(id)
                 , dest   INTEGER REFERENCES nodes(id)
                 , PRIMARY KEY(source, dest)) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO edges(source, dest) VALUES
  ((SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name='MSN'), (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name='google'))
, ((SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name='google'), (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE name='MSN'));
-- etc.
```

([Documentation for WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) if you've never seen that.)

Then the query in your question would become something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM edges AS e
JOIN nodes AS n ON e.source = n.id OR e.dest = n.id
```

Comment: this means to that i have to `INSERT INTO edges(source, dest) VALUES` for each row of a database.